# Automate the creation of a new row

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have tried `Automate.io`, and it works well with google sheets.
But have one problem.

What I want to do is:

When a new row is added on spreadsheet 1, the bot should add a new row in spreadsheet 2. But I also want it to choose a worksheet on spreadsheet 2 depending on a value.

Is that possible to do?